# QTreeWidgetItem with two parents

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

Can I somehow attach one QTreeWidgetItem to two (or more) nodes at once? Just like this:

```
parent1
 └child1
parent2
 └child1
```

If I just do `addChild()` on both parents, the child appears only on the first parent. Is that even possible? Or such result can be achieved only by completely copying of descendant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [instructions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#insertChild) say:

> If the child has already been inserted somewhere else it won't be
>   inserted again.

This means that only option is to copy the child completely. Roughly so:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* copy(QTreeWidgetItem* item)
{
    if (item == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    QTreeWidgetItem* out = new QTreeWidgetItem(*item);
    for (int i = 0; i < item->childCount(); i++)
    {
        out->addChild(copy(item->child(i)));
    }

    return out;
}
```